# PyMC3: Using AR1 process as prior causes Bad initial energy error

Tags: python, inference, markov-process

I'm fairly new to MCMC and `pymc3` in particular so apologies if this is something obvious. I'm trying to do parameter inference using `PyMC3` on what I thought was a relatively simple model defined as:

$$y_t \sim \mathcal{Poisson}(\lambda_t)$$
$$(\lambda_t - \mu) = \theta(\lambda_{t-1}-\mu) + \eta I_{t-1} + \epsilon$$

With $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $0 < \theta < 1$ and $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$.

We observe $\textbf{y} = [y_0, ..., y_T]$ and $\textbf{I} = [I_1, ..., I_T]$ and we can further assume that $\lambda_t + \mu > 0$ for all $t$ avoiding any strange behaviour with the Poisson distribution.

Since the builtin `AR1` assumes $\mu = 0$, I have modified it as below:

```
import theano as T
import theano.tensor as tt
import pymc3 as pm
from pymc3.distributions.distribution import generate_samples, draw_values

class NonzeroMeanAR1(pm.distributions.continuous.PositiveContinuous):
    """
    Autoregressive process with 1 lag.
    Parameters
    ----------
    k : tensor
       effect of lagged value on current value
    tau_e : tensor
       precision for innovations
    """

    def __init__(self, k, tau_e, mu, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NonzeroMeanAR1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.k = k = tt.as_tensor_variable(k)
        self.tau_e = tau_e = tt.as_tensor_variable(tau_e)
        self.tau = tau_e * (1 - k ** 2)
        self.mu = tt.as_tensor_variable(mu)
        self.mode = tt.as_tensor_variable(0.)

    def logp(self, x):
        k = self.k
        tau_e = self.tau_e
        mu = self.mu

        x_im1 = x[:-1]
        x_i = x[1:]
        boundary = pm.Normal.dist(mu=mu, tau=tau_e).logp(x[0])

        innov_like = pm.Normal.dist(mu=k * (x_im1 - mu) + mu, tau=tau_e).logp(x_i)
        return boundary + tt.sum(innov_like)

    def random(self, point=None, size=None):
        tau = draw_values([self.tau], point=point)[0]
        mu = draw_values([self.mu], point=point)[0]
        k = draw_values([self.k], point=point)[0]
        eps = generate_samples(sps.norm.rvs, loc=0, scale=tau**-0.5,
                               dist_shape=self.shape,
                               size=size)

        y, _ = T.scan(lambda err, prev, k, mu: k*(prev - mu) + mu + err,
                      outputs_info=mu*tt.ones((1,), dtype='float64'),
                      sequences=[eps],
                      non_sequences=[k, mu])

        return y
```

Recovering the parameters for this works just fine, as below:

```
def simple_ar(n_samples, k, sig, mu):
    out = np.zeros((n_samples,), dtype='float64')
    out[0] = mu

    for i in range(1, n_samples):
        out[i] = k * (out[i-1] - mu) + sps.norm.rvs(scale=sig, size=(1,)) + mu

    return out

y_obs = simple_ar(500, 0.9, 0.2, 100)

with pm.Model() as ar_model:
    k = pm.HalfFlat('k')
    tau = pm.HalfNormal('tau', sd=100)
    mu = pm.HalfFlat('mu')
    y = NonzeroMeanAR1('y', k=k, tau_e=tau, mu=mu, observed=y_obs)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=500)

pm.summary(trace)
         mean     sd     mc_error   hpd_2.5   hpd_97.5    n_eff      Rhat
k       0.8959   0.0208   0.0008     0.8562     0.9360  659.9843    1.0038
tau    23.4081   1.4514   0.0535    20.8658    26.4553  689.1551    0.9997
c     100.0275   0.0829   0.0028    99.8813   100.1941  792.9259    1.0038
```

However, if you go and say

```
import scipy.stats as sps
yp_obs = [sps.poisson.rvs(x) for x in y_obs]
```

And modify the model as below:

```
with pm.Model() as par_model:
    k = pm.HalfFlat('k')
    tau = pm.HalfNormal('tau', sd=100)
    mu = pm.Normal('mu', mu=100, sd=5)
    l = NonzeroMeanAR1('l', k=k, tau_e=tau, mu=mu, shape=500)
    y = pm.Poisson('y', mu=l, observed=yp_obs)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=500)
```

This simply yields `ValueError: Bad initial energy: inf. The model might be misspecified.`

Analysis of the error [as suggested here](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/getting-bad-initial-energy-inf-when-trying-to-sample-simple-model/364/2) shows that the problem lies with the variable `l`:

```
for RV in par_model.basic_RVs:
    print(RV.name, ':', RV.logp(par_model.test_point))

k_log__ : 0.0
tau_log__ : -0.7698925914732451
mu : -2.528376445638773
l_log__ : -inf
y -inf
```

However, I'm at a complete loss regarding how to fix this. Does anyone have some thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be in the `__init__` function, particularly in the line:

```
self.mode = tt.as_tensor_variable(0.)
```

It appears that when initialising the distribution, PyMC3 uses the mean of the distribution instead of drawing a sample. Replacing it by

```
self.mean = self.mu
```

Solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit after the fact and so may not have applied when the question was posted, but currently you can get the same results using the original AR1 likelihood by just translating the `y_obs` by the random variable `mu`. 
So, instead of this:

```
with pm.Model() as ar_model:
    k = pm.HalfFlat('k')
    tau = pm.HalfNormal('tau', sd=100)
    mu = pm.HalfFlat('mu')
    y = NonzeroMeanAR1('y', k=k, tau_e=tau, mu=mu, observed=y_obs)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=500)
```

You have:

```
with pm.Model() as ar_model:
    k = pm.HalfFlat('k')
    tau = pm.HalfNormal('tau', sd=100)
    mu = pm.HalfFlat('mu')
    y = pm.AR1('y', k=k, tau_e=tau, observed=y_obs-mu)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=500)
```